# What is the cross-section area of an electrode when measuring electrolytic conductivity?

Tags: measurements, electrochemistry

If we have two flat plates,

[image]

then the area is understood easily. However, if our two electrodes are like this:

[image: enter link description here]

then will we take the area of $S_1$ or $S_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

The connection between ohmic resistance $R$ and conductivity $\sigma$,

$$
\sigma = \frac{L}{RA},
$$

is based on

1. the assumption that the material follows Ohm’s Law, with the current density proportional to the electric field, $\vec J = \sigma \vec E$
2. the assumption that the electric field in the test volume is *uniform*, so that the volume integral from $\frac1\sigma \vec J = \vec E$ to $RI = V$ depends only on the geometry and not on variations in the strength of the electric field.

This second assumption is valid in a long thin conducting wire, with $L\gg \sqrt A$, because charges can rearrange on the outside of the wire to cancel out any external field.  It’s also valid in a parallel-plate capacitor geometry, with $L \ll \sqrt A$, because two *nearby* parallel plates can have negligible “fringing field.”

However, neither of your diagrams obeys the assumption of uniform field.  Your upper diagram has $L \approx \sqrt A$, which means there will be a substantial variation in the electric field through your electrolyte volume.  And your lower diagram seems to have surfaces with different areas which are not parallel to each other.  There is a volume integral in your future.